# How do I transcode a xerces XMLCh array with a limited length?

Tags: c++, xerces

The [xercesc::XMLString](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html) class has two different functions to transcode an XMLCh array to a native char *array:

`static char * transcode(const XMLCh *const toTranscode, MemoryManager *const manager=XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager)`

and

`static bool transcode(const XMLCh *const toTranscode, char *const toFill, const XMLSize_t maxChars, MemoryManager *const manager=XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager)`

According to [the documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html#87abed2b2baf335e4fbc09182989c07d), the second overload is deprecated. Documentation is sparse on the exact behavior of either function, however, and when I get an XMLCh array with a length specified (as in the [ContentHandler::characters](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classContentHandler.html#ed552fab959bfa7e9135691e1d21ab5a) handler), it seems I would want to use the method that limits the number of characters transcoded. Any clues on why the second method is deprecated, and if there are any alternative transcoding methods?

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated function requires you to supply a buffer and hence it's size.  The first (non-deprecated) function creates the buffer for you and returns a pointer to it.  They both do the same thing except the deprecated function may not be successful due to the buffer being too small.  Seems like the non-deprecated function has a cleaner interface.

Comment: Agreed, the non-deprecated function is a much cleaner interface, but how does it know when to stop reading the toTranscode array? Is it counting on the array being null-terminated? And if it's not -- do we just run right off the end, or is there some internal xerces magic that happens?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It has to keep track somehow.  Either it's documented or you can look at it in a debugger.